# Correct way of passing arguments which is an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose you have an array of two arrays. How can you make a function correctly separate the parts and apply the `lambda` function here on each of them?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([[1]])
b=np.asarray([[1,2]])
r=np.asarray([a,b])
f=lambda x,y:x[:,0]+y
print f(*r)
```

This code will rise: `IndexError: too many indices`. However simple change of `a` two a `(1,2)` array will change everything since numpy makes `r` an `ndarray` and correctly apply function to each of `a` and `b`. I understand this is because that what `f` gets for its first argument is `[array([[1]])]` but not `[[1]]`. Is there any way to generate the same behaviour in the first case as well?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([[1,2]])
b=np.asarray([[1,3]])
r=np.asarray([a,b])
f=lambda x,y:x[:,0]+y
print f(*r)
```

With output:

```
[[2 4]]
```

***EDIT***: Just to clarify since `f` will be called in my real code for million times and its more complex its important for me to keep this procedure as efficient as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a `asobjectarray()` function:

```
import numpy as np

def asobjectarray(alist):
    r = np.ndarray(len(alist), object)
    r[:] = alist
    return r

a = np.asarray([[1]])
b = np.asarray([[1,2]])
r = asobjectarray([a,b])
f=lambda x,y:x[:,0]+y
print f(*r)
```